# Using SWI-prolog

Tags: swi-prolog, embedding

Please help, how I can use SWI-prolog on machines without installed SWI? I want to create C#-application that uses SWI for some things, and it should work on machines without installed SWI. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the Prolog installation into the same folder as the C# application.
Then use these executables instead of the installed ones.
This is what I would try first.

Comment: Do you offer to move the Prolog interpreter along with the application? Then how to work with the interpreter from the C#-application?